# Can not create shared link in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, sharing

I have a file inside "iCloud Drive", folder "Downloads". I can see the file from my iMac (macOS 10.15.7) and in my iPad.

I would like to create a link to this file, which I can send to other people for downloading.

According to

https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/share-photos-and-videos-mm93a9b98683/icloud

there should be an option for creating such a link.

On the iMac:

I do a right click on the file name, then select "Share". There is no "create link" on the context menu which opens.

On the iPad:

If I click on the icon for sharing on top of the sereen, there is no "create link" either.

How can I then share a file in my iCloud drive?

**UPDATE**:

Perhaps this is OS dependent. On my MacBook, running MacOS 12.7, when I do a context click on the file in `iCloud Drive` and click on *Share*, I now have a menu entry named *Share File*, which, when clicked, opens a dialogue, which in turn lets me create the link. On my iMac (running an older OS version), this was not possible.

With iOS on the iPad, this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Linked documentation first sentence “You may share photos and videos in Photos on iCloud.com with an iCloud Link (not available in all countries or regions).” For sharing other files (and folders) refer to [Share files and folders in iCloud Drive on iCloud.com](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mm708256356b/icloud)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg : The link you are refering to, works when I log into icloud.com using by webbrowser. I was looking on a way to create a sharing link locally (similar to how Dropbox is doing it). But note the update to my question, which at least gives a partial answer for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

> On my iMac (running an older OS version), this was not possible.

To use iCloud folder sharing with your Mac, you need to be running **Catalina or later**.  Per the [minimum system requirements for iCloud features…](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230)

> #### iCloud Drive folder sharing
>
> iCloud Drive folder sharing is available on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, Mac, and PC.
>
> - iOS 13.4 or iPadOS 13.4
> - OS X Catalina 10.15.4
> - iCloud for Windows 11.1

Comment: Though this is interesting, it does not explain the behaviour I can see, because my 10.15.7 on the iMac is still newer than the 10.15.4 which you state as required. BTW, my iPad is on iOS 17.3.1.

Comment: Did you do a clean install of 10.15 or did you upgrade from a previous version?  My Catalina iMac works with iCloud drive as expected, but I always do a clean install

Comment: I always upgrade. I feel it is less risky.